# How to choose a framework for small dynamic web based projects?

Tags: test-automation-framework, selenium-webdriver

I am new to selenium webdriver and I'm confused about how to select a framework in selenium automation testing. Basically I am trying to automate a dynamic websites. 
Can anyone guide me on which type of parameters(factors) are followed to select a framework?

Comment: Do you have some example "frameworks" your are trying to pick between? Or do you mean programming languages and or unit-test runners? I don't think you really need a framework. What language are your websites created with?

Answer (score 1):

Its difficult to get an idea of what you are after without a bit more information but a bit of background;

1. Selenium Webdriver is a framework which helps you select and manipulate elements within a webbrowser.
2. Selenium is compatible with a number of languages now.  Java, C#, etc
3. You will likely need a testing framework such as JUnit or TestNG.  These allow you to perform Asserts (basically pass/fail conditions).

I have created a base suite using Java+TestNG which might help you get up and running. It's free to use, share, and Improve! 
https://github.com/ECiurleo/webdriverBase

This project uses a build manager called Maven.  This will download all the dependant files you need automatically when you open the project.  Hopefully it will give you a starting point from which to build on.

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at [Selenide](http://selenide.org). It's just a more convenient and readable Selenium.